# BGL: specialization of template in different namespace

Tags: c++, boost-graph

I am creating a graph by BGL, and would like to combine bundled properties with `vertex_index_t` as the `VertexProperty` of the graph is `listS`.

I used the method from [BGL dijkstra_shortest_path algorithm method does not accept my color map exterior property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11336723/bgl-dijkstra-shortest-path-algorithm-method-does-not-accept-my-color-map-exterio/19717509#19717509) , however, I end up with `specialization of template in different namespace` error.

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>

namespace MyNameSpace {

using namespace boost;

struct VertexP {
    std::string name;
    unsigned int id;
};

typedef adjacency_list<vecS, listS, bidirectionalS, VertexP> Graph;

class VertexIndexMap {
public:
    typedef boost::readable_property_map_tag category;
    typedef size_t  value_type;
    typedef value_type reference;
    typedef Graph::vertex_descriptor key_type;

    VertexIndexMap(const Graph& g): _g(&g) {}

    const Graph * _g;
};

template<>
struct property_map<Graph, vertex_index_t > {
    typedef VertexIndexMap const_type;
};

}
```

I tried the following code, but not work.

```
namespace MyNameSpace {

namespace boost {
template<>
struct property_map<Graph, vertex_index_t > {
    typedef VertexIndexMap const_type;
};

}

}
```

Please help me out.

***EDIT***

Below is my current solution, don't know if it's correct.

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>

namespace MyNameSpace {

using namespace boost;

struct VertexP {
    std::string name;
    unsigned int id;
};

typedef adjacency_list<vecS, listS, bidirectionalS, VertexP> Graph;

class VertexIndexMap {
public:
    typedef boost::readable_property_map_tag category;
    typedef size_t  value_type;
    typedef value_type reference;
    typedef Graph::vertex_descriptor key_type;

    VertexIndexMap(const Graph& g): _g(&g) {}

    const Graph * _g;
};

}

namespace boost {

template<>
struct property_map<Graph, vertex_index_t > {
    typedef VertexIndexMap const_type;
};

}

namespace MyNameSpace {
  // the remaining code in namespace MyNameSpace
}
```

Comment: What's unclear about the error message? You can't specialize a template changing the namespaces used for the declaration of that template type.

Answer (score 1):

A template explicit specialization should be in the scope of the namespace in which the template was defined.

Since the code you have posted is not a minimal example, here is a minimal example to reproduce the problem.

```
namespace A {
    template<class T> class X { /* ... */ };
    namespace B {
        template<> class X<int> { /* ... */ };
    }
}
```

See [Demo.](https://godbolt.org/z/doSKmr).

To make the above example compile you can move the specialization out of `namespace B`
or you can even move it out of `namespace A` provided you use a nested name specifier when you specialize it.

```
template<> class A::X<int> { /* ... */ };
```

See [Demo.](https://godbolt.org/z/j1hVbW)

Comment: I updated the code example, g++-7 will produce the same error. The problem is the type parameter declared in namespace A (or MyNameSpce in my example).

Comment: The compiler version does not matter. This is not allowed.

Comment: I add my current solution in my original post, could you review and comment it? Thanks.